# How does time period of vibration of a body depends on the shape and size of a body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, frequency, resonance, vibrations

My books mentions that time period of vibration of a body depends on the shape and size of a body. But it does not give any reason behind the fact. So I searched on the internet but failed to find any satisfactory answer. So my question is how does time period of vibration of a body depends on shape and size of a body?

Comment: As an example, check out https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37543/2451

Answer (score -1):

Ok, to understand this, you have to understand about the center of mass of the body. Different shape body have different position of center of mass. Depending upon the distance of center of mass of the body from the point of suspension, different bodies have different time period of oscillation. I hope this will help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).